# Reverse long array to string algorithm

Tags: java, string, algorithm, long-integer

i need to reverse the following algorithm which converts a long array into a string:

```
public final class LongConverter {
private final long[] l;

public LongConverter(long[] paramArrayOfLong) {
    this.l = paramArrayOfLong;
}

private void convertLong(long paramLong, byte[] paramArrayOfByte, int paramInt) {
    int i = Math.min(paramArrayOfByte.length, paramInt + 8);
    while (paramInt < i) {
        paramArrayOfByte[paramInt] = ((byte) (int) paramLong);
        paramLong >>= 8;
        paramInt++;
    }
}

public final String toString() {
    int i = this.l.length;
    byte[] arrayOfByte = new byte[8 * (i - 1)];
    long l1 = this.l[0];
    Random localRandom = new Random(l1);
    for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
        long l2 = localRandom.nextLong();
        convertLong(this.l[j] ^ l2, arrayOfByte, 8 * (j - 1));
    }
    String str;
    try {
        str = new String(arrayOfByte, "UTF8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException localUnsupportedEncodingException) {
        throw new AssertionError(localUnsupportedEncodingException);
    }
    int k = str.indexOf(0);
    if (-1 == k) {
        return str;
    }
    return str.substring(0, k);
}
```

So when I do the following call

```
System.out.println(new LongConverter(new long[]{-6567892116040843544L, 3433539276790523832L}).toString());
```

it prints **400** as result.

It would be great if anyone could say what algorithm this is or how i could reverse it.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Converting a `long[]` to a `String` doesn't make any sense, you're going to need to explain what the desired result is rather than just what the actual result is.

Comment: You don't appear to be using the rest of the array. Only `l[0]` is used so this is the only value you can hope to recreate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a solvable problem as stated because

- you only use `l[0]` so any additional `long` values could be anything.
- it is guaranteed that there is `N << 16` solutions to this problem. While the seed for random is 64-bit in reality the value used internally is 48-bit. This means is there is any solution, there if at least 16K solutions for a `long` seed.

What you can do is;

- find the smallest seed which would generate the string using brute force. For a short strings this won't take long, however if you have 5-6 character this will take a while and for 7+ character there might not be a solution.
- instead of generating 8-bit characters where all 8-bit values are equal. You could restrict the range to say space, A-Z, a-z and 0-9. This means you can have ~6-bits of randomness, shorter seeds and slightly longer Strings.

BTW You might find this post interesting where I use contrived random seeds to generate specific sequences. http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/randomly-no-so-random.html

If you want a process which ensures you can always re-create the original longs from a String or a byte[], I suggest using encryption.  You can encrypt a String which has been UTF-8 encoded or a byte[] into another byte[] which can be base64 encoded to be readable as text. (Or you could skip the encryption and use base64 alone)

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. I'll try my best to find a solution with your answer. I know it doesn't make sense to convert a long array to a string but i got this "wonderful" piece of code when I decompiled  a jar file.